# Wowza LoadBalancer

Tags: wowza

I want to implement wowza load balancer. So that my one wowza server can handle all global request and throw it to the edge servers.
I read the pdf and went to all examples they provide but still can not get how to redirect traffic and which tags to be used in Server.xml to configure

Please anyone can guide me trough or It would be very nice that anyone can share the sample of configuration from both ends

Answer (score 1):

Here is two way to follow. One of them
Wowza Origin- Edge architecture, you publish stream to the origin server and the edge server restream the origin one with stream repeater. In this case you need to know wowza edge is active or not,the other way, the proper way I use, without wowza configuration you can handle this lb with nginx or haproxy with upstream method. See details in nginx rtmp balance

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, as of mid-2020 there's a [load balancing add-on](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-get-dynamic-load-balancing-addon).

It supports all protocols except WebRTC.
There's a step-by-step guide in the Readme.html inside the archive.